# block public access to the AWS Elastick Beanstalk URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have a node.js app running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have setup a domain pointing to a CDN distribution which is pointing to the EBS. But the web app is also accessible via the ELB URL directly. I want to block public access to the EBS URL. how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom security group that allows only the IP address of the CDN. Create an .ebextensions file that will configure the environment to use your custom security group.

See: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/security-group-elastic-beanstalk/

Your CDN provider should publish their public IP address, for example here is Cloudflare: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/